# Amazon Connect as Voice Mail System

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I am trying to configure Amazon Connect as a voice mail system with this flow:

[image: Amazon Connect Flow diagram for voice mail (does not work)]

The recordings are not being loaded into our configured S3 bucket.

I stumbled on this documentation that seems to indicate that this will not work because the voicemail is being left without being connected to an agent:

[image: Screenshot from amazon that reads "A conversation is recorded only when the contact is connected to an agent. The contact is not recorded before then, when they are connected to the flow."]

where the key part is: "A conversation is recorded only when the contact is connected to an agent. The contact is not recorded before then, when they are connected to the flow."

However, it seem strange that Amazon Connect would not have some simple way to configure to leave voice mail.

My questions are:

1. How can I change my flow to allow recording?
2. Is there a simple way to setup voicemail on Amazon Connect?

BTW: I found this link but it involves setting up four lambda functions and before I go down that path I want to rule out the easy options (or just switch to twilio).

https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/voicemail-for-amazon-connect/

Answer (score 5):

Well Connect is a contact centre solution, not an ACD so no voicemail out of the box isn't that surprising.

But that link is how you can get it to handle voicemail and I have used it several times to do just that.

Edit: There is another approach. The aws-samples github has a project implementing VM but creating tasks instead of emails from the VMs that are left. This seems to me to be a better approach as it keeps track of the VMs and keeps everything in Connect.

https://github.com/aws-samples/connect-task-creation-for-voicemail

Note, I've not tried implementing this yet so can't comment about how easy/hard it is, but I wish I had known about this earlier :)

Comment: Agree. Also another advantage of this approach is that you can transcribe the voice, if you like. This is not possible with the out of the box solution.

Answer (score 2):

That blog includes a CloudFormation template that makes it super-simple to implement. I'd give that a shot before switching to Twilio, Connect is a superior platform and far cheaper to run.